# How can you make a conditional external script reference in the public html file in reactjs. i.e. one for production and one for staging

Tags: reactjs

How to script a conditional external script reference inside the public html file in reactjs.

```
<script>
  var element=document.createElement('script');

  if (env.test) {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'https://pay-sandbox.gocardless.com/js/beta');
  } else {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'https://pay.gocardless.com/js/beta');
  }

  document.getElementById("...").appendChild(element);
</script>
```

// Was thinking something like the above but don't know how to access the environmental variable from here.

```
<script>
  var element=document.createElement('script');

  if (env.test) {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'https://pay-sandbox.com/js/beta');
  } else {
    element.setAttribute('src', 'https://pay.com/js/beta');
  }
  document.getElementById("...").appendChild(element);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of in the `index.html` file, you can add [a custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) which loads the script dynamically in your App component.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

interface AppProps { }


const App:  React.FC<AppProps> = ({}) => {
  const [hasScriptLoaded, setLoadedStatus] = useState(false);
  const isDev = true; // Set this boolean by reading your env here
  const src = isDev ? 'https://pay-sandbox.gocardless.com/js/beta' : 
                      'https://pay.gocardless.com/js/beta';
  useEffect(
    () => {
        // Create script
        let script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = src;
        script.async = true;

        // Event listener for when script is loaded
        const onScriptLoad = () => {
          setLoadedStatus(true);
        };

        // Attach event listener to script
        script.addEventListener('load', onScriptLoad);
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        // Clean up
        return () => {
          script.removeEventListener('load', onScriptLoad);
        };

    },[src])
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        {hasScriptLoaded && <div>Script has been loaded</div>}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

You can play around in [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-djzyqe). Inspect the scripts being loaded in the browser in the StackBlitz and check that script is rendered according to the `isDev` variable. You can set the `isDev` variable based on the environment instead.